# Отправить данные конкретному пользователю

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, redbeanphp

я пытаюсь сделать взаимодействие админа и пользователя(ей).
У меня есть регистрация и авторизация на сайте через redbeanphp, люди создают там просто объекты и потом как бы отправляют мне(Админу) сайта, как мне человеку который отправил мне объект, из админки послать сообщение, так что бы он его увидел без перезагрузки страницы?
Понимаю что тут связь идет с Ajax и php, а куда дальше копать не знаю, подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: Копайте в сторону поисковиков. В интернете полно примеров на тему "ajax php пример"

Comment: Дело не в ajax, дело в том что я должен в админки выбрать конкретного пользователя и отправить ему сообщение(Любой текст), а у него оно должно отобразится без перезагрузки страницы, то что тут ajax и php понятно, и в поисковиках примеры только отправки формы и обработки простой) Но спасибо за направление к поисковикам - я уже целый день ищу это и пока пусто(

Answer (score 0):

1. Можно использовать push уведомления в браузер, [документация](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Push_API)
2. Можно, сделать таймер который раз в пять секунд (например) будет опрашивать сервер, и таким способом выводить уведомления.